# How to read multiple selection from a listview in WPF without MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

```
int noOfItems = list1.SelectedItems.Count;
                for (int j = 0; j < noOfItems; j++)
                {

                    s3[j] = list1.SelectedItems[j].ToString();
                }
```

This didn't work as I want values selected.
and list1.SelectedValue[j].ToString(); returns an error

Could someone help me to a feasible solution.

Comment: I always use MVVM, so I may be rusty at this, but I think SelectedItems is `IEnumerable` which means you can do `foreach(var item in list1.SelectedItems)` and then use `item.ToString()` inside the loop

Comment: @MatthewFrontino s3[j]=item.ToString()
is giving object reference not set to an instance error

Comment: @RavindraNadh it is probably your s3 array.  Do you have the code for that?

Comment: @MatthewFrontino ya...it was an error in my code at s3.
thanks that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
 string hobies = "";


        foreach (string  chk in lstHobbies.CheckedItems)


        {

            hobies +="," + chk;


        }

        txtPrint.AppendText("\r\nHobbies:" + hobies);
```

Comment: thanks...sorry for the late response, 
missed to un-comment the array initialization part.